# How to stop form submission in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

You may be amazed why I am intended to do it, but it's necessary to be done. I couldn't solve, so could you please help me.. if yes, let's go!

> I have a **form**, I want that if I click on **submit**, an action/event should be generated that stops the form submission, and tells me that your form is not submitted. That's it.

Here's my form:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form>
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" required><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" required><br>

        <input type="submit" value="submit form"/>
    </form>

</div>
```

Here's the AngularJS controller:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        // Execute form submission
        // handle data and prevent redirect

    });
</script>
```

I regret if I am asking something irrelevant, but I think it can be done to which my reach is not possible for now.

Thanks.

Comment: By default AngularJS stops the form submission, unless your form has an action attribute, which in this case it doesn't. Can you clarify your issue now that you know this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Untested by you can try swapping out for your submit button for

```
<button ng-click="submit($event)">Submit form</button>
```

And then in your controller:

```
$scope.submit = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
}
```

By not using the default form submission you get to access the event and control whether to continue with it or not.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I needed. upvote my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs exposes the [NgSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive which should be used when submitting a form

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" required><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" required><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit form"/>
</form>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.submit = function() {
            //do your thing
        };

    });
</script>
```

Warning: Don't combine the use of ng-click and ng-submit